# How i can remove all the content inside a <td> which came after the first <a>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a 3rd party application, and I have the following markup :-

[image]

Now I want to hide the text and link which comes after the "New item" link. Mainly to hide the "`or`" text and the "`edit`" link and the "`this list`" text... so how I can do this using css if possible ?
mainly to specify to remove all the content which comes after a link with `id = "idHomePageNewItem"`, where this content is specified inside the same `<td>`?

Comment: Abhishek Gurjar you messed up the OP with your edit

Comment: @RajshekarReddy I've rollbacked I'd used a plugin for edit which deleted the link as well.

Comment: *remove all the content which comes after a link* this is not possible with CSS.. **Remove** is not possible in CSS but can be done using Javascript.. However you can **Hide** in CSS.. do you have control over this html? if you can just wrap the text `"or"` and `"this list"` in a `<span>` tag then in CSS this can be done.

Comment: @AbhishekGurjar looks good now.. Happy playing "Devil May Cry" :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use query selector and for loop by specifying the id and make use of `parentElement` if you dont want to specify the classname. Hope this one helps

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="ms-list-addnew">
<a href="something" id="idHomePageNewItem">Something</a>
or
<a href="nothing">Nothing</a> Nothing
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var element = document.querySelectorAll("#idHomePageNewItem");
 for(var i=0; i<element.length; i++) { 
   element[i].parentElement.innerHTML = element[i].outerHTML
 }
</script>
```

Comment: now the problem in my case that we have multiple elements with the `ms-list-addnew` class name.. so can i make this more dynamic so i specify to just remove everything after the a with id = `idHomePageNewItem` till the next `</td>`

Comment: U mean u want to remove everything after `id = idHomePageNewItem` for every td with class name `ms-list-addnew`, like using a for loop or You have other other divs with class name `ms-list-addnew`

Comment: Not exactly.. Now i have one link with id = `idHomePageNewItem`.. so i want after selecting this element using `var k = document.getElementById('idHomePageNewItem');`  to remove everything that comes after it,, till the `</td>`.. is this possible ??

Comment: what i want to remove is the `or` text the next `<a>edit</a>` link and the `this list` text.. so is this possible ?

Comment: I currently don't know if that's possible to remove everything from `a` tag to end of a some tag. Will update my answer once I came across that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for this.

```
 $(".ms-list-addnew a:not(:first)").hide();

 $(".ms-list-addnew").contents().filter(function () {
     return (this.nodeType == 3);
  }).remove();
```

Comment: now in my case there are multiple elements which contain the class `.ms-list-addnew`.. so your script did not have any effect..

Comment: You can add an id and use that ID for the selector, i used your class name as an example to point out the tag